# Remove quotes inside foreach loop for a Javascript object - Laravel 5.4 - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, laravel-5.4

Im trying to display some listings on a map, but Im having trouble displaying the 'targetSVG' in the  section because it contains "" (quotes). I show you what I mean:

This is how its displaying now in the view source code section:
[image]

As you can see, the "targetSVG" displays quotes, I need to remove them.

This is how Im setting the objects in the controller:

```
$listingLocations = Location::all();

$locations = [];

foreach( $listingLocations as $location ){
    $locations[] = ['svgPath' => 'targetSVG', 'zoomLevel' => 5, 'scale'    => 0.5, 'title' =>  "$location->listing_id", 'latitude' => $location->latitude, 'longitude' => $location->longitude ];
}

return view('admin.dashboard', compact('locations'));
```

How would I remove the quotes inside that foreach loop, particularly just for the 'targetSVG'.

I tried:
json_decode
json_encode
str_replace
stripslashes

This is how Im appending it in the Javascript

[image]

/*** UPDATE ***/

Thats the outcome I wanted, I guess I can just insert the actual SVG code in the controller:

```
foreach( $listingLocations as $location ){
            $locations[] = [
                'svgPath' => 'M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z',
                'zoomLevel' => 9,
                'scale' => 0.5,
                'title' =>  "$location->listing_id",
                'latitude' => $location->latitude,
                'longitude' => $location->longitude
            ];
        }
```

Comment: You can't remove the quotes...would be invalid json. Not clear what objective is or what you expect `targetSVG` to represent

Comment: I updated question, with answer

Comment: so where does the value come from? Question/problem is not clear

Comment: Is `targetSVG` meant to refer to a JavaScript variable defined elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it was a Javascript variable

Comment: @David Yeah, JSON can't do that. You need to either do what you did or echo JavaScript code directly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will probably just echo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through your array in the javascript and assign the variable value there:

```
var targetSVG = // your value 

data.forEach(function(item){
  item.svgPath = targetSVG 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could only remove slashed if the entire 'collection' was one string. Otherwise you made a JSON object which has to have value in quotes if it is a string - like in this example.